# Create a trigger that listens for a row to be inserted into two separate tables at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in SQL Server that will trigger when two rows will be inserted into two separate tables with the same exact time stamp.

Is this possible to do as a trigger? My understanding is that a trigger is attached to only one table. Has anyone attempted this before?

Comment: can you provide an example scenario?

Comment: You are right - you cannot possibly do this, since a trigger is **always** associated with **exactly one** table

Comment: Sure we have a program that when a record is created an "Interaction" table it also creates a contact for who owns that interaction. So, this process creates a record in the interaction table and the contact table at the exact same time. I would like to listen for this exact scenario and log that this is how this contact record was created because the system has no clue this record was created by this process. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: you will need to create a trigger on each of the said tables then a stored procedure that checks to see if a result has been entered then handles the event.

Comment: @marc_s So, is there a way to do this with multiple triggers or should I right more of a batch style solution to this. I would like to happen right when the process happens, but if I can't then o well.

Comment: @KamranFarzami Do you mind elaborating what you have in mind. Would the triggers call this stored procedure?

Comment: @user214260: I would definitely use a scheduled SQL job to check those tables e.g. once every hour (or whatever frequency you need) to detect these situations. This is not a good fit for a trigger (or multiple triggers)

Comment: @marc_s This was my first thought, but my boss suggested a trigger so I figured I would see if I could see if that would even be possible.

Comment: @user214260: Triggers do add overheads to your table operations. I think  marc_s has the right idea